# UITableViewCell only shows content on selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview in my view controller. In my iPhone simulator content is shown just fine but, in iPad simulator cells are white. When I select a cell, it shows content in gray color. I have 2 storyboards for iPhone and iPad. These two storyboards' tableviews have same attributes(identifier and custom cells are identical). Has anybody faced a situation like that. 
[image: Content is shown just in the first cell because at that time, I selected the cell.]

Comment: white over white, will result in white. Your icons are there, you see them because the selection is grey

Comment: white over white? normally background color is clear color. Also selection is blue color.

Comment: @mayy00 On iOS 7 on iPad there is a bug on UITableView cells that overrides the background color set form IB. It will always be white unless you change it from code.

Comment: thanks a lot dude, post is as answer and I will accept it